"smaller to larger" vs "smallest to largest"
Would it be ok to say "from smaller to larger" or do I have to say "from smallest to largest"
E.g., I'm using the batteries from smallest/smaller to largest/larger capacity.

If you order things by size, the first one is the smallest and the last one is the largest.  Why do you want to use the comparative?

That's a fair point, I was just hesitating between the two

Unless there are only 2 sizes.

If you're loosely grouping batteries on say a five-point scale, 'from smaller to larger' conveys this rather better than 'from smallest to largest', which implies an accurate ordering. On Ludwig.com: 'The phrase "from smaller to bigger" is correct and usable in written English.
You can use it any time you want to demonstrate a progression from a lower size/amount/value to a greater one. For example, "The balloons increased in size, progressing from smaller to bigger as the children watched in excitement." '

@EdwinAshworth I see the difference now, that was very clear thank you!
